# SSH connection refused. Error 61

Tags: ssh, freebsd

So, I set up another FreeBSD server. Everything was ok until I tried to connect to it via my old FreeBSD.

On connection it echoes:

```
Unable to connect to relay host, errno=61
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

But I just used Putty to connect to it and it works. On top of it, I had connected to my old via SSH with no problem. It still can't connect to new one.

**TL;DR:**

SSH

- Win->Old = ok
- Win->New = ok
- New->Old = ok
- Old->New = *no_go*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What messages do you get in the security log from the ssh server on the new host?

Comment: Maybe the new ssh server request stronger encryption (or newer protocol) than the old client can do. Run `ssh` with `-vvv` flag to see more information about the internals. Do you have configured some unreachable ssh proxy/relay host on the old freebsd system (the error message seems to confirm this)?

Comment: @jofel that's where I was heading, too.

Comment: ssh -vvv sshpokedummy@192.168.0.212
OpenSSH_4.5p1 FreeBSD-20061110, OpenSSL 0.9.7e-p1 25 Oct 2004
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /usr/local/sbin/proxy-connect -S 192.168.0.1:1080 192.168.0.212 22
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1001
debug1: identity file /home/fisher/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/fisher/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/fisher/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
FATAL: Unable to connect to relay host, errno=61

Comment: they both have same proxy\relay i can connect to old from new, but fails to do so from old

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the output of the `ssh` command to it, so it can be formatted properly.

Comment: The problem is probably not `ssh` but the to me unknown `proxy-connect` program. Does the SOCKS proxy work from the old bsd machine if you are using it for other connections (web browsing etc.)? Can you ping 192.168.0.1 from the old machine? Do you need the proxy or is a direct connection possible (seems to be same subnet)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to a not-found matching private key. The ssh client sequentially tries several keys (from .ssh/) which are denied by the server, until a limit is reached. 
Try to specify a specific identity with

```
ssh -i .ssh/<correct key> ....
```